# Sorting linked list by manipulating pointers

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, linked-list, shellsort

I'm trying to implement Shell sort on a linked list. I divide my original linked list into sub linked list, which contain nodes that have 'k' gap regarding the shell sort algorithm. I want to sort the sub linked list by manipulating the 'next' pointers instead of changing its data field. So I have a `sortList` function that traverses the linked list and swaps the nodes with `swapNodes` if it encounters any unordered nodes.

When I pass an unordered linked list with two elements to the `sortList` I keep loosing one of the nodes in my list. For example, I have 50 and -84 in my list, I pass it to `sortList`. After the `sortList` figures that they're unordered it calls `swapNodes`, but once `swapNodes` terminates, the resulting list only has 50.

I tried to gdb and found out that when I'm in `swapNodes` scope the list gets sorted successfully without losing a node, but when it terminates and turns back to `sortList` scope, both the `head` and `curr` points only to 50 and their 'next' field is NULL.

My functions:

```
void sortList(Node * head, long * n_comp) {
    Node * curr;
    int didSwap = 1;
    while(didSwap) {
        didSwap = 0;
        for(curr = head; curr -> next != NULL; ) {
                *n_comp += 1; //number of comparison
                if(curr->value > curr->next->value) {
                    swapNodes(curr, curr->next, &head);
                    didSwap = 1;
                } 
                curr = curr -> next;
                if (!curr) break;
            }
    }
}
```

```
void swapNodes(Node * p1, Node * p2, Node ** start) 
{
    Node *p1pre = NULL;
    Node *p1curr = *start;
    while (p1curr && p1curr!=p1)
    {
        p1pre = p1curr;
        p1curr = p1curr->next;
    }
    Node *p2pre = NULL;
    Node *p2curr = *start;
    while (p2curr && p2curr != p2)
    {
        p2pre = p2curr;
        p2curr = p2curr->next;
    }

    if (p1pre != NULL)
    {
        p1pre->next = p2curr;
    }
    else
    {
        *start = p2curr;
    }
    if (p2pre != NULL)
    {
        p2pre->next = p1curr;
    }
    else
    {
        *start = p1curr;
    }
    Node *temp = p2curr->next;
    p2curr->next = p1curr->next;
    p1curr->next = temp;
    return;
}  
``
```

Answer (score 1):

It's happening for the same reason why you gave `start` type `Node**` in the first place: your node [50] is being moved and `head` moves with it instead of staying at the start of the list. You need to change your sortList method so the parameter `head` also has type `Node**`:

```
void sortList(Node ** head, long * n_comp) {
    Node * curr;
    int didSwap = 1;
    while(didSwap) {
        didSwap = 0;
        for(curr = *head; curr -> next != NULL; ) {
            std::cout<< "It: " << *n_comp<< std::endl;
            *n_comp += 1; //number of comparison
            if(curr->value > curr->next->value) {
                swapNodes(curr, curr->next, head);
                didSwap = 1;
            }
            curr = curr -> next;
            if (!curr) break;
        }
    }
}
```

Now your head will stay at the start of the list.

Note: this is one of the reasons why [sentinel nodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Sentinel_nodes) are a thing.